# How to access nested json object with json?

Tags: mustache

This super simple test is giving me difficulty if I plug in the following extremely simple JSON and template. How do I access "s.name"?

Template:

```
<p>{{s.name}}</p>
```

JSON:

```
{s:{name:"S"}}
```

I also tried this template - still won't work:

```
<p>
{{#s}}
  {{name}}
{{/s}}
</p>
```

Am I missing something? How can I access s.name of the JSON?

Comment: Doesn't just {{name}} work.. Used it a long time ago.

Comment: @Sajit - No... That won't work

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid because the keys are not strings. With valid JSON, either of your solutions work [as demonstrated on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/ekJzx/).

`{"s":{"name":"S"}}`

Comment: Interesting...I came to the conclusion it doesn't work even after trying "strings" for JSON because it isn't working on the demo site for mustache at - http://mustache.github.com/#demo